# Lay out HTML elements depending on the number of elements

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

The issue is that I have to lay out from 2-4 html video elements, but the number is dynamic, sometimes can be 2, 3, or 4 elements.

With 2 I will lay them out both side by side, 3 elements will be displayed as a "T" (I mean 2 videos side by side above, and one in the middle below), and 4 elements will be displayed as a hollywood square (2 side by side above and the same below).

The elements will be like this one, and could be wrapped in divs or whatever:

```
<video id="streaming1" width="100%"  height=auto autoplay></video>
<video id="streaming2" width="100%"  height=auto autoplay></video>
...
```

The issue is that I'm not pretty sure if I could include directives in these video elements (but yes in a div which contain them) that why maybe I want to do it directly in a controller (though I know that DOM manipulation shouldn't be done in controller but directives, but that's why I am asking for help).

And I don't know how to start to manage this, I'm lost cause I am quite new with angular/javascript and not an expert in css.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of using CSS to get the layout that you want.

If your HTML looks like this (for 2,3 and 4 video elements respectively):

```
<div class="video-panel">
    <video id="streaming1" height=auto autoplay></video>
    <video id="streaming2" height=auto autoplay></video>
</div>

<div class="video-panel">
    <video id="streaming1" height=auto autoplay></video>
    <video id="streaming2" height=auto autoplay></video>
    <video id="streaming3" height=auto autoplay></video>
</div>

<div class="video-panel">
    <video id="streaming1" height=auto autoplay></video>
    <video id="streaming2" height=auto autoplay></video>
    <video id="streaming3" height=auto autoplay></video>
    <video id="streaming4" height=auto autoplay></video>
</div>
```

try to following CSS:

```
.video-panel {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2.00em; /* for demo only */
}
video {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    width: 48%;
}
```

see demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Um4mP/

If you need more control over the margins around the `video` elements, you can apply `display: inline-block` to the `video` CSS rule and adjust margins and paddings as needed.

The one thing to be careful of is any whitespace between the `video` elements, which will add to the overall width of the line.  I used a width of 48% instead of 50% to avoid unexpected wrapping due to any whitespace (line returns in this example).

Comment: this is a big step forward, thanks. What about using Angular to have more control over the elements and (I don't know) if would have to do whatever with them. I would like to find an approach using Angular also. But your reply helped me a lot.

Comment: You can create specific CSS rules (classes) to create the exact margins and padding that you need for each case of 2, 3 and 4 videos (for example).  You can then use AngularJS to determine the number of videos and apply the appropriate class, but I don't quite know the details of how to do that with AngularJS, but I am pretty certain that it can be done.

Comment: My issue now is that I want to wrap them in a div and I want the videos to take the maximum space possible inside that div independently from the number of video tags. Setting that div with a defined size.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail: "wrap them in a div" Do you want to create a one-column display of all the videos?

Answer (score 1):

WORKING DEMO : **http://jsfiddle.net/4Th4j/**

HTML :

```
<div class="vid">
    <div class="one">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x150"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="vid">
    <div class="three">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.vid{
    background:#dadada;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.one,.two,.three,.four{
    width:50%;
    background:#eaeaea;
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0px;
}
img{
    border:none;
    width:50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here you can place the `<img>` or `<video>` tag inside the one,two,three or four div.
It will automatically center the element of only one element is in row.

Answer (score 0):

There a plenty of solutions to this problem.

I assume you are pulling the videos from some backend?

Therefore I would use angulars ngRepeat directive to give the elements different classes dependant on the total number of elements.

From here I would assign these classes with the relevant CSS to get the desired layout.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: You are right, these videos come from a backend an that <video> elements with the video itself are injected directly from backend to the webpage, the number of videos can change dinamically sometimes can be 2 other 3 or 4 (by now, it's expected to be scalable to 'n' videos).
Do you think ngRepeat is the best solution? there would be any example or something to lay out elements, either video or pictures or whatever using this technique?
Thanks in advance.